# python で入力を加算していくアルゴリズムについて

Tags: python, アルゴリズム

このように、入力値を加算していくにはどのようなプログラムを組めばよいでしょうか？言語はPythonでお願い致します。

**入力値:**

```
200 
300
500
100
200
```

**出力:**

```
200
500
1000
1100
1300
```

Comment: 頭の中にやり方はあるけれどコーディングが分からないということでしょうか？やり方がまとまらない場合はフローチャートを書くとすっきりするかと思います。そうではなくコードに落とせない場合は質問者さんがどの程度Pythonが書けるかを質問に追記されると良いかと思います。

Answer (score 2):

初期値は 0 で、入力を受け取るごとに加算をしていくような一時変数を使うと良いです。「順番に足していく」ということをしているので、その途中の「ここまで入力された値を全部加算した値」をメモしておく、という形です。

具体的な実装としては、入力を `int(input())` で受け取って加算する、というのを繰り返すループを書くことになります。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
参考にして書いてみます

Answer (score 0):

Whileループで十分ですが、この中で数字を要求し、追加します。入力した数値が 0 の場合にのみ、別の条件を設定できる場合にのみ、サイクルを停止します。

```py
num = 0
while True:
    n = int(input("number: "))
    if n==0: break #stop loop
    num+=n
    print(num)
```